# How do I fix an login error ( black screen with cursor on top left corner )?

Tags: 14.04, brightness

Actually I've faced problem in adjusting the brightness in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Afterwards, I've configured the "20-intel.conf" file with the following command

```
         sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Then, it invoked the file "20-intel.conf". In this file, I've added the following lines

```
Section "Device"

Identifier "card0"

Driver "intel"

Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"

BusID "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

After doing so, I restarted the system. **Afterwards, OS is getting booted up and not showing the login screeen as well as showing the black with cursor located at top left corner.**

Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please help me to fix this problem.